# How to set values to ViewBag in ActionFilterAttribute ASP MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I would like to create my custom ActionFilterAttribute for each controller in my application, this attribute should set some ViewBag values. Is ActionFilterAttribute  would be fine for it and how to get access to viewbag in ActionFilterAttribute  ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can do like this

```
public class SomeMsgAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
        }

        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Msg= "Hello";
        }
}
```

Using:

```
[SomeMsg]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any explanations about why this works in `Executing` but not in `Executed`?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen `OnResultExecuted` is invoked after the razor view is rendered. By that time, it is too late to change the output.

Comment: I see, I always thought it as `OnResultExecuted` invoked immediately after the action method returned, pity :) I should've thought it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void
    OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //  get the view bag

        var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;

        // set the viewbag values
        viewBag.CustomValue = "CustomValue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For ASP.NET Core you can do the following

```
public class SomeFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
{
     public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {
         Controller controller = context.Controller as Controller;

         controller.ViewBag.CustomValue = customVal;
         controller.ViewData["CustomValue "] = customVal;
         controller.TempData["CustomValue "] = customVal;
     }
}
```

Then from the controller

```
    [TypeFilter(typeof(ValidateAppFeatureEnabled))]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var foo = ViewBag.CustomValue;
        var bar = (type)ViewData["CustomValue"];
        var buzz = (type)TempData["CustomValue"];

        // Whatever else you need to do

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To transfer data from a different controller action

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    EmployeeTrackingSystemAndMISEntities db = new EmployeeTrackingSystemAndMISEntities();

    var UserCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["UserUniqueID"];


    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "UserLogIn");
    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Login");

    var TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData;
    TempData["Status"] = "Please log in as Admin";

    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);

}
```